# magento 1.8 auto check subscribe to newsletter

Tags: php, magento, newsletter

YES i know this topic has been covered, however, out of the 6 different options/posts/tutorials, none of them have worked for me.

I just need to change the "Signup for newsletter" text to something better like "Get Receipt and notifications"  AND make it CHECKED to on.

NOW, the problem is, i have followed 6 tutorials, and none of them work.

NOTHING i change on the file affects magento.  I even purposely deleted 3/4 of the page and put in a bunch of keyboard slop and DESTROYED the file, uploaded it, and it did not a D#&$ thing!!!   NOTHING affects this file!

As you can see i'm way WAY more than frustrated.

I've even tried clearing the caches.

---

the LAST one i did, said to change THIS:

```html
<li class="control">

                    <div class="input-box">

                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />

                    </div>

                    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>

                </li>
```

TO THIS:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="is_subscribed" value="1" id="is_subscribed"  />
```

and save it....

The file i am working with is

/public_html/app/design/frontend/galaeva/default/template/customer/form

anyone  please??????

Comment: Yeah, so i just tried COMPLETELY deleting the file altogether, and it still runs like a cockroach with it's head cut off.   i don't get it.......  i really really don't get it....

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mage_Persistent module enabled and Persistence is enabled from:

```
System >> Configuration >> Persistent Shopping Cart >> Enable Persistence
```

then file which is called for customer registration, login etc will be called from:

**app\design\frontend\\\template\persistent\customer\form** folder.

Please check whether this is in your case or not.